# Moving a smart pointer from one unordered_set from another

Tags: c++11, move, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, unordered-set

```
template<class T>
Class Node
{
    //irrelavant functs
};
class A
{
    unordered_set<unique_ptr<Node<T>>, myHash<Node<T>>, myEqual<Node<T>>> nodes
    shared_ptr<A> child;

    void moveToChild()
    {
        for(auto it = nodes.begin(); it < nodes.end(); ++it) {
            if (some_cond) {
                child->nodes.emplace(std::move(*it));
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I have a class that holds bunch of nodes in unordered_set, and has a pointer to itself called child. When some arbitrary conditions satisfied, this class should move some (or all) of its pointers to Node objects to child's nodes container. But I'm not sure if it's possible since keys in unordered_sets are const.

I don't mind constructing a new smart pointer, but I can't afford to construct a new node every time I move it around or remove it from unordered_set. If what I'm trying to do is not possible with unique_ptrs, I was wondering if it's possible with shared_ptrs?

I have never implemented my own allocators for STL containers so not sure if I'm on the right track but I was thinking of writing a custom allocator for unordered_set that takes a bool, if it's true, it deletes the objet if it's false it doesn’t free the pointer but removes it from the container (again, not sure if I can make such a dramatic change to container's behavior)

So, is it possible to somehow move a smart pointer from one unordered_set to another without freeing it?

Note: Please don't pay attention to typos and syntax errors, it's a grossly simplified version of my code.

Comment: You would need to erase the vector elements from the parent list if you were transferring to the child.

Comment: @AndyG I'm willing to create a temporary shared_ptr and erase the original one from the set, but I'm not sure if I can do that without freeing the object smart pointer points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs afool of `std::set` only returning its elements by constant reference, using `<` on iterators, not removing the disemboweled elements from the `std::unordered_set` and some insignificant typos.

```
void moveToChild() {
    for(auto it = nodes.begin(); it != nodes.end();)
        if (some_cond) {
            child->nodes.emplace(std::move(const_cast<nodes::reference>(*it)));
            // Must const_cast above because the set only gives constant access.
            it = nodes.erase(it); // Remove element
        } else
            ++it;
}
```

Comment: At least for me, on GCC 8.3.0, I get a segfault when trying to do this. As far as I can tell, `erase(it)` needs the contents of that element to be valid, so it can compare it with other internal items, etc. But if the guts have been `std::move`'d, it crashes. In general, it's not safe to do arbitrary things with an object after it has been moved, and I don't know that `erase` makes any guarantees about what it may or may not do under the hood.